# xquery filter on attribute and element

Tags: xpath, xquery

I have the following simple XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cars>
    <car>
        <data attrib="Make">
            <text>Volvo</text>
        </data>
        <data attrib="Model">
            <text>855</text>
        </data>
    </car>
    <car>
        <data attrib="Make">
            <text>Volvo</text>
        </data>
        <data attrib="Model">
            <text>745</text>
        </data>
    </car>
    <car>
        <data attrib="Make">
            <text>Volvo</text>
        </data>
        <data attrib="Model">
            <text>V70R</text>
        </data>
    </car>
</cars>
```

And the following XPath:

```
/cars/car/data[(@attrib='Model') and (text='855')]
```

This returns the following result:

```
<data attrib="Model"><text>855</text></data>
```

I want the XPath to return the whole `<car>` block for the match.

So return data would be like this:

```
<cars>
    <car>
        <data attrib="Make">
            <text>Volvo</text>
        </data>
        <data attrib="Model">
            <text>855</text>
        </data>
    </car>
</cars>
```

How would I modify the XPath expression above to achieve this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

XPath returns whatever node you go up to - in your case you're going to `data`, so that's what you're getting back. If you want `car` instead, place your predicate after `car`.

```
/cars/car[data/@attrib='Model' and data/text='855']
```

Or, slightly shorter

```
/cars/car[data[@attrib='Model' and text='855']]
```

XQuery to produce the desired output:

```
<cars>
  {/cars/car[data[@attrib='Model' and text='855']]}
</cars>
```

Comment: Just to add to this response: this will return the selected "car" element. It won't wrap this in a "cars" element as requested. Because the input doesn't contain an existing "cars" element with only one child, you can only achieve this output by constructing a new "cars" element, and for that you will need XQuery rather than XPath.

Comment: To add to @MichaelKay 's comment, it is even easier and more natural to do such processing with XSLT rather than with XQuery.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev could you give an XSLT example please ?

Answer (score 3):

**Here is a complete and likely one of the shortest possible XSLT solutions:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <cars>
       <xsl:copy-of select="car[data[@attrib='Model' and text='855']]"/>
   </cars>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, the following transformation, using the wellknown **[identity rule](http://web.archive.org/web/20081229160200/http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** is both easier to write and provides maximum flexibility, extensibility and maintainability:

```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
         </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="car[not(data[@attrib='Model' and text='855'])]"/>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When either of these two transformations is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<cars>
    <car>
        <data attrib="Make">
            <text>Volvo</text>
        </data>
        <data attrib="Model">
            <text>855</text>
        </data>
    </car>
    <car>
        <data attrib="Make">
            <text>Volvo</text>
        </data>
        <data attrib="Model">
            <text>745</text>
        </data>
    </car>
    <car>
        <data attrib="Make">
            <text>Volvo</text>
        </data>
        <data attrib="Model">
            <text>V70R</text>
        </data>
    </car>
</cars>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<cars>
   <car>
      <data attrib="Make">
         <text>Volvo</text>
      </data>
      <data attrib="Model">
         <text>855</text>
      </data>
   </car>
</cars>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The first transformation generates the top element `cars`, then simply selects the wanted `car` element and copies it as the body of `cars`.
2. The second transformation is based on one of the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design patterns -- using and overriding the identity rule.
3. The identity template copies every matched node (for which it is selected to process) "as-is".
4. There is one template overriding the identity rule. This template matches any `car` for which it is not true that `data[@attrib='Model' and text='855']`. The body of the template is empty and this results in nothing from the matched `car` element being copied to the output -- in other words we can say that amy matching `car` element is "deleted".